R for GIS - calculating proximal densities
I recently started using R for GIS applications and need assistance with calculating proximal densities, a concept I am mostly unfamiliar with. To illustrate, suppose I am provided with schools and playgrounds location data for which I would like to calculate proximal densities at 0.25-mile, 0.50-mile, 0.75-mile, and 1-mile radii. How can this be achieved using R program? This is what I have tried so far.
# load required packages
library(sp)
library(sf)

# create standard rectangular non-spatial data frames
schools <- data.frame(Location = c("Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL"), Place = c("Albertville Middle School", "Albertville High School", "Albertville Intermediate School", "Albertville Elementary School", "Albertville Kindergarten and PreK", "Albertville Primary School"), Lat = c(34.25996, 34.260509, 34.27279, 34.25182, 34.29161, 34.25321), Long = c(-86.2074, -86.205116, -86.220818, -86.22271, -86.19384, -86.22192))
playgrounds <- data.frame(Location = c("Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL"), Place = c("Graham Park", "Sand Mountain Park", "Pecan Grove Playground"), Lat = c(34.26358, 34.275471, 34.27294), Long = c(-86.20289, -86.229111, -86.2264))

# define the coordinates
schools_coords <- cbind(schools$Long, schools$Lat)
playgrounds_coords <- cbind(playgrounds$Long, playgrounds$Lat)

# create the SpatialPointsDataFrame
schools_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(schools_coords, data = schools, proj4string = CRS("+proj= longlat"))
playgrounds_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(playgrounds_coords, data = playgrounds, proj4string = CRS("+proj= longlat"))

# convert to sf
schools_sf <- st_as_sf(schools_sp)
playgrounds_sf <- st_as_sf(playgrounds_sp)


Your link requires authentication, please add direct links instead. Also, please do include the code that you have so far. This will give others a starting point for their answers. For instance, are your data dataframes, or are they spatial objects (created using the sf, sp et al. packages)? Answers that are minimal, reproducible examples are much easier to answer. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

@LTyrone, thank you for your comment. I have added my data in the R code. I have also included some code that I think should be the starting point.

The workflow:

determine appropriate UTM zone CRS (or use one you know is appropriate). This assumes your coordinates are WGS84/EPSG:4326.
create sf objects for schools and playgrounds and project to CRS determined from previous step
create buffers at specified distances in metres (radii) e.g. 400 == ~0.25 miles and sum playground counts per school buffer
combine all buffer sf files and calculate proximal density

It is necessary to project your data to a projected coordinate system (PCS) to ensure the buffer area calculations remain relatively constant for your buffers across the extent of your research area. If your data are at national level, or extend across multiple UTM zones, you may need to run separate calculations for each UTM zone. You could also pre-calculate area values and assign them to the buff* files, but let's keep things simple-ish for now.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Your sample data
schools <- data.frame(
  Location = c("Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL"),
  Place = c("Albertville Middle School", "Albertville High School", "Albertville Intermediate School", "Albertville Elementary School", "Albertville Kindergarten and PreK", "Albertville Primary School"),
  Lat = c(34.25996, 34.260509, 34.27279, 34.25182, 34.29161, 34.25321),
  Long = c(-86.2074, -86.205116, -86.220818, -86.22271, -86.19384, -86.22192)
  )

playgrounds <- data.frame(
  Location = c("Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL", "Albertville, AL"),
  Place = c("Graham Park", "Sand Mountain Park", "Pecan Grove Playground"),
  Lat = c(34.26358, 34.275471, 34.27294),
  Long = c(-86.20289, -86.229111, -86.2264)
  )

# Get UTM zone 
floor((schools$Long + 180) / 6) + 1
# [1] 16 16 16 16 16 16
floor((playgrounds$Long + 180) / 6) + 1
# [1] 16 16 16

# Create sf objects and project to correct UTM zone (or whatever CRS is appropriate)
# EPSG codes can be found @ https://epsg.io/
sf_schools <- schools %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(32616)

sf_playgrounds <- playgrounds %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(32616)

# School buffers
buff25 <- st_buffer(sf_schools, 400) %>%
  st_join(., sf_playgrounds, join = st_contains) %>%
  group_by(Place.x) %>%
  summarise(pg_count = sum(!is.na(Place.y)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(buff = "buff025")

buff50 <- st_buffer(sf_schools, 800) %>%
  st_join(., sf_playgrounds, join = st_contains) %>%
  group_by(Place.x) %>%
  summarise(pg_count = sum(!is.na(Place.y)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(buff = "buff050")

buff75 <- st_buffer(sf_schools, 1200) %>%
  st_join(., sf_playgrounds, join = st_contains) %>%
  group_by(Place.x) %>%
  summarise(pg_count = sum(!is.na(Place.y)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(buff = "buff075")

buff10 <- st_buffer(sf_schools, 1600) %>%
  st_join(., sf_playgrounds, join = st_contains) %>%
  group_by(Place.x) %>%
  summarise(pg_count = sum(!is.na(Place.y)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(buff = "buff100")

# Combine buffers, calculate area as square miles, calculate proximal density,
# convert to dataframe, pivot to wide and reorder buffers from smallest to largest
buff_all <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^buff\\d{2}$"))) %>%
  mutate(area_sq_mile = as.numeric(st_area(.)) * 3.861e-7,
         pd = pg_count / area_sq_mile) %>%
  rename(Place = Place.x) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Place,
              names_from = buff,
              values_from = pd) %>%
  relocate(buff100, .after = last_col())

buff_all
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   Place                             buff025 buff050 buff075 buff100
#   <chr>                               <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Albertville Elementary School        0       0      0       0    
# 2 Albertville High School              5.16    1.29   0.573   0.322
# 3 Albertville Intermediate School      0       1.29   1.15    0.644
# 4 Albertville Kindergarten and PreK    0       0      0       0    
# 5 Albertville Middle School            0       1.29   0.573   0.322
# 6 Albertville Primary School           0       0      0       0

The values in the buff* columns represent the proximal density of playgrounds around each school per square mile.

Thank you for the detailed answer. This helps me a lot. Could you share any tips on how to determine the appropriate CRS?

@StatisticsFanBoy - you're welcome. Using UTM zones is a robust approach in most cases. So running unique(floor((schools$Long + 180) / 6) + 1) then web search "EPSG UTM zone x" where x is the result of the previous code. The first result is usually from https://epsg.io/. Also, this link, and the cheat sheet pdf from that link are good starting points.

@StatisticsFanBoy - if you are wanting a workflow to manage data across multiple UTM zones, you could do df$UTM <- floor((schools$Long + 180) / 6) + 1 and then run your analysis on each group in df$UTM. Hard to describe the full workflow in a comment, so if you need further assistance, search for an existing SO answer regarding data across multiple UTM zones. If none help with your use case, ask a new question. Myself, or another SO denizen, will gladly help.

creative use of mget() +1

@LTyrone, I just learned a way to calculate CRS from UTM and thought I would share it with you. It is simply CRS <- 32600 + UTM for a location in the northern hemisphere or CRS <- 32700 + UTM for a location in the southern hemisphere.
